# In java why does FileWriter throw IOException while FileOutputStream throw FileNotFoundException for the exact same reasons

Tags: java, filenotfoundexception, ioexception, filewriter, fileoutputstream

From [java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html)

public FileWriter(String fileName) throws IOException

Throws:

**IOException** - if the named file exists but is a directory rather than a regular file, does not exist but cannot be created, or cannot be opened for any other reason

and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html)

public FileOutputStream(File file, boolean append) throws FileNotFoundException

Throws:

**FileNotFoundException** - if the file exists but is a directory rather than a regular file, does not exist but cannot be created, or cannot be opened for any other reason

Is there a specific reason for this choice?

Comment: FileOutputStream can only fail when file is not found. FileWriter can fail when file is not found, or for other reasons.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Interesting question.

I just peeked into each constructor's code, which helped clarify things:

`FileWriter` uses a `FileOutputStream`. The `FileOutputStream` throws a `FileNotFoundException`, which extends `IOException`.

`FileWriter extends OutputStreamWriter` whose constructor throws `UnsupportedEncodingException`, which also extends `IOException`.

`FileWriter`, therefore, can throw either exception. But since they both extend `IOException`, it declares `IOException` in its constructor's signature.